# Adicionar linha no final do arquivo com o comando sed

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant, sed

Estou configurando uma máquina virtual para instalar o JDK 7, Tomcat 7, JBoss EAP 7 e Postgresql. Segue o projeto no GitHub para quem tiver interesse: [cresol-enviroment-vagrant](https://github.com/softfocusbr/cresol-enviroment-vagrant).

Estou na parte em que é preciso adicionar o `JAVA_HOME` no arquivo `/etc/profile`, porém ao executar o seguinte comando:

> sudo sed -i 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk7u79' /etc/profile

Esta retornando a mensagem de erro:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `J'

Como posso fazer para adicionar corretamente as linhas que dizem respeito ao caminho do diretório do JDK?

**Referências:**

[Instalação e Configuração do JDK 7](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Instalacao-e-Configuracao-do-JDK-7)

Answer (score 4):

Também dá pra resolver este problema sem usar o `sed`:

```
sudo echo $JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk7u79 >> /etc/profile
```

Comment: (+1) mas parece-me que o `$a` está a mais.

Comment: Correto, @JJoao. Obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo sed -i -e '$aJAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk7u79' /etc/profile
```

Answer (score 0):

> Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
echo 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH' >> /etc/profile
```

> Veja mais no meu [script no gist](https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/a7bd30288342a5d352e6).